# Textarea CSS Selector Based on Value

Tags: html, css, reactjs, user-interface, frontend

I have a textarea HTML element, and I want to have it styled differently before interaction, while interacting and post interaction.

Relevant css:

```
.multiline-input {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.multiline-input:focus {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  outline: 0.5px solid rgba(87, 85, 247, 0.74);
}

.multiline-input:not(:focus):not([value=""]) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  outline: 0.5px solid #e1e1e8;
}
```

The problem is that the `:not([value=""])` selector has no effect. Can I achieve this goal in another way?

Comment: `.multiline-input:not(:focus).multiline-input:not([value=""])` is the selector for a **single** element. Did you mean to comma-separate them? `.multiline-input:not(:focus), .multiline-input:not([value=""])` If the selector is for when the element is not focused and the element is not empty, this is the correct selector: `.multiline-input:not(:focus):not([value=""])`

Comment: Thanks for the improvement suggestion, but it doesn't solve it issue mentioned :(

Comment: `[value=""]` - that's an attribute selector, but `textarea` does not _have_ a `value` attribute.

Comment: How so? the typed content is kept in a state and is passed to the textarea through value attribute - and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
.multiline-input {
      background-color: #f7f7f7;
    }

    .multiline-input:focus {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      outline: 0.5px solid rgba(87, 85, 247, 0.74);
    }

    .multiline-input:not(:focus):valid {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      outline: 0.5px solid #e1e1e8;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! thing is this component may is used in a form and may be optional. I don't want to force it into being required for the styling to work.